# System Generator:How to know how many clock cicles are nedeed for my FFT block?

Tags: clock, xilinx-system-generator, fft

I would like to know how many clocks cycles the FFTv4_1 require?
Does anyone know how to determine the required clock cycles?  I am using the System Generator 9.2i version.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Simulate in Modelsim? Also, surely there will be a report that you can generate to get timing information like this. The manual is likely the best place for this info - I just checked and it has a detailed chapter on timing analysis (p329 onwards)

Answer (score 1):

calculating the FFT is not a "FIXED" clock cycle operation. It depends largely on the sample block size and the number of Add/Multiply/Address Fetches are calculated. the FFT algorithm takes care of the ADD/Mutliple/Address Fetching optimization. However, you need to specify the number of samples this is being applied to.